# NEC MultiSync Resolution Problem

Tags: windows-7, resolution

I have a slightly odd issue with my monitor, an NEC MultiSync LCD1970NXp. I'm running Windows 7 Ultimate on a Toshiba Tecra M5 laptop, and according to Windows Update I have the latest drivers.

When I restart the laptop on the docking station at work with the monitor attached, it runs under 1024x800, but the optimum resolution for the monitor is 1280x1024, which isn't an available resolution in the Windows Screen Resolution dialog.
If I restart the laptop undocked e.g. at home, it goes to 1280x1024, which is the resolution of the laptop screen. If I subsequently hibernate it and then wake it up on the docking station, the monitor then quite happily displays at 1280x1024.

Can anyone suggest what the problem might be, or a method by which I can restart on the docking station and still get 1280x1024.

Comment: What kind of dock is it (make/model)?

Comment: It's a Toshiba one - I believe http://uk.computers.toshiba-europe.com/innovation/jsp/individualOptions.do?service=UK&selCategory=4697&oldCategory=4697&OPTION_ID=1059171&toshibaShop=true is it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rebuilt this laptop last week with Win 7 Ultimate. At some point while I was out of the room it must have found and installed a driver because when I came back to it it was running at 1280x1024. I guess an updated driver got released.